# dynamically select jquery UI tabs based on hash ID from a text link inside tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, tabs

I have a set of jQuery UI tabs that is generated by a CMS, so content will be different for every page. Some tabs sets could have two tabs, others could have 5 etc.

I have looked around for a simple solution to this but cant seem to find it.  i have looked at the history plugin as well as alternate codes.

Here's my sample markup

```
<div id="tabs"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB 1 HEADING</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB 2 HEADING</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">TAB 2 HEADING<a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4">TAB 3 HEADING</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="tabs-1">tab1 content here</div>
<div id="tabs-2">tab2 content here</div>
<div id="tabs-3">tab2 content here</div>
<div id="tabs-4">tab4 content here</div>
```

I want to create a script that allows the user to alternately select a tab from a text link within the tabbed content. So for example, in the tab content div, have  that links to the 3rd tab, as the tab navigation does.  I don't want to have to manually code the index of the desired tab in the script.

I know this will work, but want to create something that is more robust across all my tabbed content.

```
$("#tabs").tabs("select" , "#tab-4");
```

Here is what i have so far, but doesnt seem to work. I am new to jQuery. I have added an onlick called tabJump to the anchor links.

```
function tabJump(){
    //get href ID as a number
    var thisID = Number($(this).attr('href').replace(/#tabs-/, '')) - 1;
    // this should trigger the new tab based on this href id.
    $("#tabs").tabs("select" , "#tabs-" + thisID);
};
```

And ideas on how i could get this to work? Essentially i want whatever the id of the tag as the href of the anchor link being clicked, and to target the new tab by this given id. I would want to have multiple instances of a link with these id hrefs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ok thanks guys, finally figured out what i needed.

I'll share below in case anyone finds this useful.

initiate function on click

```
<p><a href="#tabs-4" onclick="tabJump(this);">my text link</a></p>
```

and the script

```
function tabJump(obj) {
//grab the id in the clicked links href
var thisID = Number($(obj).attr('href').replace(/#tabs-/, ''));
//use this ID to trigger the click on the set of tabs
$("#tabs").tabs("select", "#tabs-" + thisID); 
//then scroll to the top of the tabs set
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#tabs").offset().top
 });
```

};

So the way i'm using this is once the content in the tabs has been created in articles in my CMS, I'll end up with say 4 or 10 tabs. Then there's some copy in the first tab that needs to link to say, tab 4. So i add an onclick to the link and attach the jQuery script whenever i need it, as illustrated above.

Thanks guys for the help and the tips. If anyone has a cleaner way of doing this, feel free to post.

Peace

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly if this is what you need, but see if this works.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EP6Cd/).

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>This is tab ONE</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="next">Go to next tab</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" class="prev">Go to prev tab</a></p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>This is tab TWO</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="next">Go to next tab</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" class="prev">Go to prev tab</a></p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>This is tab THREE</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="next">Go to next tab</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" class="prev">Go to prev tab</a></p>
</div>
```

```
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs div a").on("click", function(){
    var idx = Number($(this).parent().parent().attr('id').replace('tabs-','')) - 1;
    if($(this).attr('class') == 'next'){
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected", idx + 1 );            
    }
    else{
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected", idx - 1 );
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hi hsalama,
thanks for this, i have something similar working, where the next tab can be selected from the text link, but i'd like to be able to say instead of +1, reference the unique id of the tab so it can essentially 'jump' to any given tab.

Sure other's may find your code helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your function `tabJump` might works. Just need to change the call for the method `select` to use just the number(thisID) instead of concatenating with the String "#tabs-".

Like this:

```
function tabJump(){
    //get href ID as a number
    var thisID = Number($(this).attr('href').replace(/#tabs-/, '')) - 1;
    // this should trigger the new tab based on this href id.
    $("#tabs").tabs("select" , thisID);
};
```

Comment: hi @Tulio

I have also tried that and this:
`$("#tabs").tabs("select" , "#tabs-" + thisID);`
But with no luck. For some reason it wont trigger the change in the tabs :(

Comment: Could you show how are you calling the function `tabJump`? Because I tried passing the anchor link element as a parameter instead of using `this`, just for testing, and it seems to have worked.

Comment: sure - on a `<p>` tag, i have an `<a onclick="tabJump();" href="#tab-4">my link</a>`. Do you think this is a good way to do it?

Comment: Ok, so try to change it to: `<a onclick="tabJump(this);" href="#tabs-4">my link</a>` and then change your `tabJump` to receive a parameter and use it instead of using `this`. Notice that I changed your call for the function and also your `href` text that was missing and "s" at "#tabs-4". I also forked @hsalama's fiddle to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/nJyHW/

Comment: About this way of doing it, actually I would rather have a `class` on the anchor link, like .tab-switch, and apply the code of the `tabJump` function for it after the page loads. Maybe it would be more elegant :P